# change 14.0.4 32 bit install to 14.0.4 64 bit

Tags: system-installation

I installed 14.0.4 32bit ubuntu, but I need install 14.0.4 64 bit. what's the best way to change to 64 bit OS

Comment: Take all backup and fresh install the ubuntu 64 bit on it

Comment: There is no way to convert, you have to reinstall

Answer (score 0):

You can install alongside 32 bit, just select to use the same partitions, and don't format the main partition.  You will keep both installs, and they will share files.  You will be given an option in GRUB for 'advanced options for Ubuntu', under which will be the various kernel versions.  One will be 32 bit, another will be 64 bit.  64 bit will be the default.

I did this with 14.04 to 15.04.  There is no option to upgrade 14.04 to 15.04 without first upgrading to 14.10.  I just installed alongside, and didn't lose anything.  Not even configuration or newly installed apps.